# Eigenfunction basis of Laplacian on a manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

It is a well known result that for $\Omega$ bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a basis of $C^\infty$ eigenfunctions of the Laplacian for $L^2(\Omega)$. It is also known that there exists a basis of $C^\infty$ eigenfunctions of the Laplacian for $L^2(M)$, $M$ being a compact, connected Riemannian manifold. It can be proved with the fundamental solution of the heat equation (see http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253/Lecture13.pdf). My question is : can the second result be proved with the first one ? In other words, can we use the eigenfunction basis of the spaces $L^2(U_i)$ ($U_i$ being the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ associated to an atlas on $M$) to build the eigenfunction basis of $L^2(M)$ ? If anybody has an idea or a reference, that would be awesome.

Thanks !

Comment: Which Hodge $\star$ are you using on each?

Comment: If $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$, there is no such basis.

Comment: @TrialAndError Sorry, my bad, $\Omega$ is bounded

Comment: @AHusain Sorry, I don't know anything about Hodge theory, I'm currently learning with Canzani notes, I'm just trying to link the 2 results with a partition of unity on $M$

Comment: @Morlock2987 The metric you are using to define Laplacian. Namely for the $U_i$.

Comment: @AHusain On $M$, the Riemannian metric; on $U_i$, the standard Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So not regarding $U_i$ as a chart?

Comment: I don't understand, yes the $U_i$'s are charts of an atlas on $M$, what is the relation with the metrics ?

Comment: I see you got what I was trying to give the hint for at as an explicit answer on MathOverflow.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks for your help !